# asp.net saving string to SQL including line breaks for formating

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to be able to store strings in the DB but some are long and i want to format them such that when i copy them out of SQL and past them into notepad they have line breaks to break up the otherwise single line that runs on forever and hard to read.

lets say i am storing a string of all the session variables like this, how do i include line breaks in here?

```
StringBuilder theBody = new StringBuilder();

theBody.Append("Session Values: " + "\n");
foreach (string s in Session.Keys)
theBody.Append(s + ":" + Session[s] + "\n");
```

Comment: How are you writing strings to SQL now?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider changing those `"\n"` to [`System.Enviornment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) instead. And also, you can use [`AppendLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebk18257.aspx) instead of `Append`.